# is it possible to not reload user control when redirect to a page?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a user control for side menu navigation and when user clicks on one of the item on a menu, it displays details of the company and information. Now it is redirecting to different page for each company using passing parameter (ex. company.aspx?ID=10) and everytime when I clicked, it refreshes whole page. I would like to keep side menu user control without refresh as there is a live search option.

Is this possible? or should I change opposite way to do it? should be the side menu in a page and company info in a user control??

Comment: How did you make that clickable items? For example, server control like  HyperLink, Button, LinkButtons or just html a tag?

Comment: Hi Win It is a dynamic menu item with using xml. So there is no button or hyperlink. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a proper way using Ajax, you'll need to change the entire site structure. Here is a quick and dirty way of doing it using jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#left-pane a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();            
            loadUrl($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });

    function loadUrl(url) {        
        $("#right-pane").load(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Win Thanks for the answer. So that means I have to change it to the opposite way for proper way using Ajax? left menu has to be in a page and right panel has to be a user control? Thanks!!

Comment: YES, the method you mention is a correct one - you can use UpdatePanel  which Ann L mentions. The alternative method is Ajax using jQuery (StackOverflow uses jQuery), but you need some experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're talking about is partial page update, where, rather than posting and reloading the entire page, you only reload part of it.

Here's a good article:  [Understanding Partial Page Updates with ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)

Comment: Hi there Thanks for your answer. I know that is an another way to do it but It is too much job to do. So rather than doing that way, I am not sure if there is another way to do it. I guess page redirection will refresh the page anyway so there seems to be no way to do it but if you have any idea, that would be much appreciated. Thanks